# Express: static files not found when using ejs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, ejs

I want all my requests to be redirected to a index.ejs view, located in the Views folder. In my routes.js file, I've added this:

```
  module.exports = function (app) {

  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.render('index', {title: "TODO"})
 });
}
```

The index view contains all of page's markups as it will be a SPA, so I will dynamically swap views  on the client-side.

The problem is that I references scripts located in the public folder and they are not found, I get a 404 :

```
script src="public/app/app.js"></script>
```

I think it's because Express does not know how to server the file. I've specified that everything in the public folder should be static files:

```
   app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'))
```

Now if I don't use ejs template and if I use a index.html file in the public folder instead of a view, it works fine. I just have to do that instead:

```
 app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
 });
```

But I want to take advantage of ejs template for adding bundles to page instead of adding scripts one by one.

So what is wrong with my code ?  How can I solve that 404 on the javascript files ?

Comment: If you're using a static route for static files after the dynamic routes, are you expecting the dynamic routes to not match? Not sure I get it, but why would you even need routes if everything is static?

Comment: only the javascript and other resources (css, images) are statics. There is only one route to the same view (index.ejs) because it's a single-page application. However it seems that when I redirect requests to that one view, static resources are no longer found.

Comment: Is the path for the static resources correct? Do you just get a 404 in the browser, or do you have errors in the Node console ?

Comment: both chrome and node consoles show a 404 on the resource /public/app/app.js.

Comment: Then the path is not correct, either your files aren't there, or you somehow got the path wrong, or the static middleware isn't working, hard to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. The path to the script file was incorrect. It should be app/app.js instead of public/app/app.js

I think this is how the static middleware works.